# How to put some text in the center of a bootstrap row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-system

There is a row which has four `col-sm-3` columns. I need to put some text in the center of this row which means the text need to span the 2nd column and the 3rd column.

### [Here is my Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/DETc95eyrI)

Here's some code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:yellow">123</div>
  <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:green">456</div>
  <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:red">789</div>
  <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:grey">000</div>
</div>
```

Plus: To clarify,I need the text to be overlayed on the same line.

Comment: What do you want the text to do on small screens once the columns stack?

Comment: @kyleMit I don't take responsiveness into account...just help me to solve this in big screens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add

```
<div class="text-center">Center aligned text.</div>
```

Before all of those columns like this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="text-center">Center aligned text.</div>
  <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:yellow">123</div>
  <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:green">456</div>
  <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:red">789</div>
  <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:grey">000</div>
</div>
```

But if you want something to take only set amount of columns, then you need another row and offset like this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
    <div class="text-center">Center aligned text.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:yellow">123</div>
  <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:green">456</div>
  <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:red">789</div>
  <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:grey">000</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: If you want that text to span/float literally over those two spans, then you will need something similar like "Shawn Taylor" suggested

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:yellow">123</div>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="position:relative;">
    <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%;" class="text-center">Center aligned text.</div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:green">456</div>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:red">789</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:grey">000</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ,this is not what i want...I need the text to be overlayed on the same row

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="background-color:yellow">123</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="background-color:green">456</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="background-color:red">789</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="background-color:grey">000</div>
</div>
```

You just need to put "text-center" on any parent div that you want text centered into.

[Updated Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/PsWW8czbb8)

If you want text spanned across above everything, then you would do

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-offset-3 text-center col-md-6">Text Centered</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="background-color:yellow">
    123
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="background-color:green">456</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="background-color:red">789</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="background-color:grey">000</div>
</div>
```

Then it won't go past the green and red (http://www.bootply.com/v3UP7Mjy4s).

Answer (score 2):

position:relative and position:absolute on a parent and child row within your center 2 columns will sort this out for you:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="background-color:yellow">123</div>

  <div class="col-md-6" style="position:relative;">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="col-md-12 text-center" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:1000;color:white">I'm spanning!</span>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center" style="background-color:green">456</div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-center" style="background-color:red">789</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="background-color:grey">000</div>
</div>
```

It's not pretty, but it works!

http://www.bootply.com/PsWW8czbb8